# Permission denied while running make install

Tags: install-from-source

I am trying to install gtk-server. First I typed the command `./configure` and then `make`, but when I typed command `make install` it gave me this error:

```
osama@osama-HP-Compaq-6910p:~/Downloads/gtk-server-2.3.1-sr$ make install
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/bin/gtk-server': Permission denied
mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
/usr/bin/install -c gtk-server /usr/local/bin
/usr/bin/install -c stop-gtk-server /usr/local/bin
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/bin/stop-gtk-server': Permission denied
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you are installing an application and used `./configure` without the `--prefix=` option the `make install` process will install the compiled files in to the predefined paths in your system's file system.

Because you are installing to your system's file system you need special permissions for writing the files, try:

```
sudo make install
```

This will elevate your user's permission to root and allow the compiled files to be installed in directories that your user does not have permissions to do so.

You can clearly see that the issue is a permission problem by the error message (*cannot create regular file cannot create regular file `/usr/local/bin/gtk-server` and `/usr/local/bin/stop-gtk-server`*): the user that is trying to install these (in this case you) does not have permissions to  write on those directories.

Comment: bruno it worked . i tried sudo make install. thanks

Comment: Bruno, I'm trying to make install Qyoto and I'm getting the same complaint.  I've run it with sudo, and I've tried sudo su, but always the same result.  Is there any other circumstance that you know of for this problem?